# Declaring function arguments in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have two functions (one of which is called inside the other) which share some variables as arguments, as the following example:

```
Public Function f1(a as Double, b as Double, c as Double)
"code"
End

Public Function f2(a as Double, b as Double, c as Double, t as Integer)
var = f1(a, b, c)
"code"
End
```

Is there a way to declare the recurring variables (a, b, and c) only once outside both of these functions, something like this:

```
Dim a As Double, b As Double, c As Double

Public Function f1(a, b, c)
"code"
End

Public Function f2(a, b, c, t as Integer)
var = f1(a, b, c)
"code"
End
```

or are those arguments specific to their parent functions?

Comment: No there isn't, but depending on what you're trying to achieve, you could consider passing an instance of a Class or user-defined type whose properties correspond to a, b and c.

Comment: @CyanD are these function called from an Excel cell as **UDF** ? or calling them from a `Sub` within the same module ?

Comment: Oh ok. Thank you for your reply.
It is for a college assignment and we haven't learned about class modules yet. 
I'll just declare explicitly for each variables then.

Comment: @Shai Yes, they are used in cells.
We have only covered functions, so no Sub yet.

Comment: FYI: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20455/is-it-wrong-to-use-the-word-codes-in-a-programming-context

Comment: @trincot Thanks for the correction. :P

Answer (score 0):

a way to do it, define global variable and don't use them as parameters for your function.

```
Dim a As Double, b As Double, c As Double

Public Function f1()
"code use a,b and c"
End

Public Function f2(t as Integer)
var = f1()
"code use a,b and c"
End
```

Comment: In response to a question as to whether these functions are UDFs, the OP stated "Yes, they are used in cells".  If that is so, function `f2` will need to be passed all four parameters - Excel won't be able to directly set the module-scoped variables `a`, `b` and `c`.